# Cancelled cheque or cancel cheque?

Tags: adjectives

If **cancelled** is not an adjective then why we use the term "cancelled cheque"? What is **cancelled** here?

Comment: Why do you think it's not an adjective here?

Comment: Because 'cancelled' is past participle form of 'cancel'. Yes it is modifying noun cheque but no dictionary consider it as an adjective.

Comment: The [past participles](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_participles.htm) of verbs are often used as adjectives.

Comment: I know that past participle are often used as adjective but why can't we use cancel (noun) here?

Comment: @Rocky Because "cancel" isn't an adjective. "Cancelled" is (or at least can be, as Michael Harvey clarified). You could say "cancel _a_ cheque" but then this is a verb phrase, not a noun phrase. When you _cancel a cheque_, then the cheque is _cancelled_.

Comment: While dictionaries do show some uses of _cancel_ as a noun, they are not common, and not used in any sense relevant to cancelling a cheque. So, in all relevant senses, _cancel_ is not a noun

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it as a participle modifying a noun, or as an adjective formed from a participle modifying a noun.

It is very common for participles to be used as modifiers, in just the same way as adjectives.  Some participles have certainly become adjectives:  bored, broken, tired etc.  Others, like "cancelled" only get used as adjectives in particular situations, such as "a cancelled cheque" (although nobody actually uses cheques anymore, so this is more a historical term now)

And just as you don't say "break leg" (you say "broken leg") or "bore student" (bored student) you don't say "cancel cheque".  In all these cases you can understand the meaning from the related verb:  "something broke the leg... it is a broken leg"

Comment: Americans would write _a canceled check_ I think.